# Find the root of $f(t)=0.05-e^{-2t}(1+2t+2t^2+\tfrac{4}{3}t^3)$

Tags: exponential-function, roots, closed-form

I am looking for the root of $f(t)=0.05-e^{-2t}\left(1+2t+2t^2+\tfrac{4}{3}t^3\right)$,
with $t>0$.

I know it is possible to numerically find the root $t_0$ using Newton's method.
However, is it possible to derive the closed-form solution?

I came up with the following equivalence:
$$
f(t) = 0.05 - e^{-2t}\left(e^{2t}-\sum_{i=4}^\infty \frac{(2t)^i}{i!} \right)
$$
but I fail to see how that may be useful to find the root.

Comment: I doubt there is a closed form...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe. There IS one

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I say "I doubt"... By the way, is a form using special functions considered as a closed form ?

Comment: What is the context of the equation?

Comment: ["Closed form"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) does not really have a precise mathematical meaning.  Basically, you are allowed to use well-known functions, but what is "well-known" to Claude may not be "well-known" to me.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe. Sorry for the delay ! Nowdays, I start seriously wondering what is a closed form. Is even $\sin(x)$ one of them ? Is it because it bears a name that it is a closed form ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Out of curiosity, what “closed form” did you think of when you said “There IS one”?

Comment: @TymaGaidash. The generalized Lambert function as IV wrote it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The

> $$e^{-2t}\sum_{n=0}^3 \frac{(2t)^n}{n!}-0.05$$

looked very similar to a [gamma regularized $Q(a,x)$ series represenation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=GammaRegularized%5Ba%2C+x%5D+%3D%3D+Sum%5Bx%5Ek%2Fk%21%2C+%7Bk%2C+0%2C+-1+%2B+a%7D%5D%2FE%5Ex+):

$$Q(4,2x)=e^{-2x}\left(\frac{4x^3}3+2x^2+2x+1\right)=0.05$$

Now use [inverse gamma regularized $Q^{-1}(a,x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inversegammaregularized) to get:

$$x=\frac{Q^{-1}\left(4,\frac1{20}\right)}2$$

[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5E%28-2x%29%284x%5E3%2F3%2B2x%5E2%2B2x%2B1%29%2Cx%3D1%2F2.0+inversegammaregularized%284%2C1%2F20%29). An interpretation is a $5$th percentile for a [chi squared distribution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Chi+square+distribution) of $8$ degrees of freedom. Maybe someone else can find an integral/sum representation.

Answer (score 2):

$$0.05-e^{-2t}\left(1+2t+2t^2+\frac{4}{3}t^3\right)=0$$

We see, this is an algebraic equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($t,e^{-2t}$). The main theorem in [Ritt 1925] cannot help in these cases: We cannot read an [elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) inverse function over a non-discrete domain directly from the equation because we don't know how to rearrange the equation for $t$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

$$0.05\ \left(e^t\right)^2-1-2t-2t^2-\frac{4}{3}t^3=0$$

We see, this is an irreducible algebraic equation of both $t$ and $e^t$. According to the theorems in [Lin 1983] and [Chow 1999], such kind of equations cannot have solutions except $0$ that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) or explicit elementary numbers respectively.

$$0.05\ (e^t)^2=1+2t+2t^2+\frac{4}{3}t^3$$
$t\to\frac{x}{2}$:
$$0.05e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{6}x^3$$
$$\frac{0.05}{1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{6}x^3}e^x=1$$

We see, this equation cannot be solved in terms of [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) but in terms of Generalized Lambert W:

$$\frac{6\cdot 0.05}{6+6x+3x^2+x^3}e^x=1$$
$$\frac{0.3}{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_2)}e^x=1$$

$x_{1,2,3}$ are the solutions of the polynomial equation $6+6x+3x^2+x^3$. You can get them in closed form.

$$x=W\left(^{\ \ \ \ 0.3}_{x_1,x_2,x_3};1\right)$$
$$t=\frac{1}{2}W\left(^{\ \ \ \ 0.3}_{x_1,x_2,x_3};1\right)$$

So we have a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for $t$, and the series representations of Generalized Lambert W give some hints for calculating $t$.
$\ $

[[Ritt 1925] Ritt, J. F.: Elementary functions and their inverses. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 27 (1925) (1) 68-90](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1925-027-01/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9/)

[[Lin 1983] Ferng-Ching Lin: Schanuel's Conjecture Implies Ritt's Conjectures. Chin. J. Math. 11 (1983) (1) 41-50](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43836165)

[[Chow 1999] Chow, T.: What is a closed-form number. Am. Math. Monthly 106 (1999) (5) 440-448](http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf)

[Mező 2017] Mező, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mező/Baricz 2017] Mező, I.; Baricz, Á.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)